# Event/observer pattern broken by _beforeSave() method override, in several Magento classes that extend Mage_Core_Model_Abstract

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When trying to implement an observer in order to catch `'cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before'` events, I've come to realise that the `_beforeSave()` method in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` overrides that of `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` *without calling its parent*, thus preventing the system from dispatching the usual `'model_save_before'` and `$this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before'`events...

In `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`:

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    //...
    Mage::dispatchEvent('model_save_before', array('object'=>$this));
    Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_before', $this->_getEventData());
    return $this;
}
```

In `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item`:

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    //...some other stuff, but no parent::_beforeSave()!
    return $this;
}
```

Although I'm very new to Magento, this looks weird to me, especially when looking at many other Magento classes which extend `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`, override the `_beforeSave()` method, but *do* call `parent::_beforeSave()` (in various ways, as can be seen in the following examples).

For instance, in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`:

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    //...
    parent::_beforeSave();
    //no return in this one!
}
```

In `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Compare_Item`:

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    parent::_beforeSave();
    //...
    return $this;
}
```

Or in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract`:

```
protected function _beforeSave()
{
    //...
    return parent::_beforeSave();
}
```

Etc.

Even weirder, `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` also overrides the `_afterSave()`, but this time *does* call the parent's method:

In `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item`:

```
protected function _afterSave()
{
    parent::_afterSave();
    //...
    return $this;
}
```

**My question is** (intended for Magento gurus out there):
Do you understand whether there is any good reason for this omission of `parent::_beforeSave()` in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item`?
Or should it be listed as a bug?

The only fix I have thought of, in order to be able to catch `'cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before'` events, is to copy the whole `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` class from `core` to `local`, and add a call either to `parent::_beforeSave()`, or directly to `Mage::dispatchEvent('cataloginventory_stock_item_save_before', ...)`.
Isn't this solution a bad hack?

Having searched (just by curiosity) in the many other direct descendents of `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`, I've found that alongside with `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item`, only two other subclasses share the same problem, at least as far as the `_beforeSave()` method is concerned (I haven't checked other basic events such as `_afterSave` and so on): ``` Mage_XmlConnect_Model_Application``and ```Mage_Dataflow_Model_Batch`.
Which leads me to think that this omission in only three classes may not have been done on purpose...

So: is it a bug, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what is meant by "meringue" in this context, but this is one of several examples in which the *targeted* `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` auto-fired events...

- *_load_before
- *_load_after
- *_delete_before
- *_delete_after
- *_delete_commit_after
- *_save_before
- *_save_after
- *_save_commit_after

...are broken.

This occurs due to either the failure of a subclass to call the parent template method when overridden (as you mention) or due to the failure to override the `_eventPrefix` in the subclass. To me this has always seemed to be an omission rather than an intention.

In this case of `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::_beforeSave()` this seems to be an omission. Up through the [1.3.2.4 version](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.3.2.4/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php#L424) of this class the method duplicates the targeted event logic (though it omits the dispatch of `model_save_before`). The [1.4.0.0-alpha2 version](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.4.0.0-alpha2/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php#L441) of this file sees the `_eventPrefix` property being added, though the failure to call the parent `_beforeSave()` method results in the loss of this targeted event.

The only intention I can see in this instance may be to force the developer to manipulate the cataloginventory object as the `stock_item` property in the context of the the product save process, but that would merit a code comment.

Comment: Sorry for my use of this silly Scottish joke about "or a meringue"... ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!
I'm glad to see I was not completely off track. Like you, I had found, in the git history, the disappearing of the event dispatching. The existence of this dispatching in pre-1.4 versions had made me wonder whether there had been a good reason to remove it...

Comment: Anyway, do you agree that the only fix is to copy the whole class from core to local, and correct it?

Comment: You have now enough reputation to voteup, your question was usefull for me and so was the answer but it was my last upvote for today ;)

Comment: Even in version 1.7.0.2 the parent::_beforeSave(); is missing from the Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::_beforeSave() and no event is dispatched there ether.